# How can I implement something like an "around each" callback in junit 5?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have some existing runner code for JUnit 4 which runs a test multiple times until it passes.

It essentially boils down to this:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= maxRetry; i++) {
    boolean failed = false;
    try {
        methodBlock(method).evaluate();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        failed = true;
        if (i == maxRetry) {
            eachNotifier.addFailure(e);
        }
    } finally {
        if (!failed || i == maxRetry) {
            eachNotifier.fireTestFinished();
        }
    }
    if (!failed) {
        break;
    }
    if (i < DEFAULT_RETRY) {
        logger.warn("Retrying " + i + " of " + maxRetry);
    }
}
```

**Note:** What `methodBlock(method)` returns is a `Statement` which runs the test including all the `@Before` and `@After` methods.

Looking through the available extension points in JUnit 5, I did find `InvocationInterceptor#interceptTestMethod`, but if I use that, it looks like it will only re-run the test method itself, not the befores and afters.

Is there anything at all similar to what we're doing in JUnit 4?

*Ideally* I'd just like something like RSpec's `around(:each)`, where given a block of test logic I can wrap it in whatever logic I want.

There's someone with a similar goal in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181026/junit5-how-to-repeat-failed-test) where the accepted answer is to *replace* the `@Test` annotation with a new annotation to indicate the test (e.g. `@FlakyTest`), and that does work, but if you have a test with both `@FlakyTest` and `@ParameterizedTest`, it fails to run. (I'd like something I can continue to use *alongside* `@Test`.)

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer, the only thing you can hope for is to open a defect against `@ParameterizedTest`, or even better provide a PR that fixes the issue

Comment: @Eugene But it isn't an issue, except in the sense that missing features are issues (if you're implying that there is no such feature?)

Comment: right, its a feature that does not yet exist

Comment: @Eugene certainly as far as what I'd like to do, [the exact feature is already ticketed](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1558) but it looks like there might be some resistance to adding the feature itself. I guess I could try creating a ticket for the extension point and see what happens.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but maybe DynamicTest might be of use (https://www.baeldung.com/junit5-dynamic-tests) ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe nah this is more about wrapping _many tests throughout the code_ in a block of surrounding code. e.g., if the test must be run on the EDT you can intercept the invocation of the method to run the method on the EDT, but you currently have to wrap the test method and the befores/afters separately, whereas for the purpose of retrying the test after a failure we'd prefer to wrap the entire test invocation as a single unit. (Currently we can implement the retry only for the test method itself.)